# Textbox to MySql in ASP

Tags: mysql, sql, asp.net, textbox

Trying to get a user entered text box to save in MySQL database.

Using code below get error :

```
`Line 57:  conn.Open();
Line 58:  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();`
```

Tried various things but never done this before and stuck. Any pointers mush appreciated.

aspx code

```
<asp:panel defaultbutton="Submit" runat="server"><asp:textbox id="textbox3" 
placeholder="Answer here" runat="server" CssClass="inputcss" /><asp:button 
id="Submit" runat="server" CssClass="submitcss" Text="Submit" value="Answer 
here" onclick="Button1_Click" />
```

aspx.cs code

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
using (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection conn = new 
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection(connString))
{
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand cmd = new 
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand();
cmd.Connection = conn;
cmd.CommandText = "CALL learners(@stickTwistBefore);";
cmd.Parameters.Add("@stickTwistBefore", 
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDbType.String).Value = textbox3.Text;
conn.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
Response.Write("SQL Error:  " + ex.Message.ToString()+ "Var:  "+  
datepicker.Text+"StrVal:  "+strDt);
}
}
```

Comment: How does it fail?  Is there an error?  Unexpected behavior?  When you debug, where does any behavior or runtime value differ from what you expect?

Comment: When I run it I get the following error    `Line 57:  conn.Open();
Line 58:  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();`

Comment: Those aren't errors, those are lines of code.  An *error* is usually in the form of an error message, as well as a particular action or set of inputs which produces that error message.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a workaround with sql server.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string constring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conn"].ConnectionString;
    try
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constring))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_qms_GetTicket", con))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stickTwistBefore", textbox3);
                con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write("SQL Error:  " + ex.Message.ToString() + "Var:  " +
        datepicker.Text + "StrVal:  " + strDt);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ashish   Tried the above code but get the following error when I run it.            Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Error CS1061 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Text' and no extension method 'Text' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)  Its on the datapicker line. Any ideas ?